# Serialization object to Json and convert back - Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have these two classes:

```
public class MyParent
{
    public string a;

    public MySub[] b;
}

public class MySub
{
    public int sub;
}
```

I initialize them like this:

```
myPC = new MyParent();
myPC.a = "test";
myPC.b = new MySub[2];

myPC.b[0] = new MySub();
myPC.b[1] = new MySub();

myPC.b[0].sub = 1;
myPC.b[2].sub = 2;
```

But when I serialize the object, The result is only `{"a":"test"}`

```
string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(myPC);
Debug.Log(json); // {"a":"test"}
```

How do I do that correctly and convert JSON back to an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally, `JsonUtility` uses the Unity Serializer; therefore the object you pass in must be supported by the serializer: it must be a MonoBehaviour, ScriptableObject, or **plain class/struct with the Serializable attribute applied**.

To ensure a custom class can be serialized, it needs the Serializable attribute
and must follow these rules:

1. Is not abstract
2. Is not static
3. Is not generic, though it may inherit from a generic class

Change your custom class to this:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class MyParent
{
    public string a;
    public MySub[] b;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class MySub
{
    public int sub;
}
```

For more in-depth information on Script Serialization, check the official documentation: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html

Comment: what is `@SerializeField` it get an error `A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods`

Comment: Are you using C# or UnityScript?

Comment: Seems like C#, in that case, its `[System.Serializable]`

Comment: wow, thankiu, it working perfect :)

Comment: @DeLe You are welcome, glad I could help.